# Has the name Althus been used before in a Fantasy series?

Tags: names, fantasy-genre

Not sure if this question is ok here or not but...

I am writing a fantasy novel and I have named my main character Althus and I am just wanting to make sure that it has not been used before...

Thanks for your help.

P.S. I have googled but my googling skills seem limited and I came up with nothing conclusive.

Comment: [Althalus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Redemption_of_Althalus) has, but I just Googled "Althus fantasy" and the top result was this question.

Comment: I know... The Redemption of Althalus is one of my favorite novels... I also did a google search but only came up with Althuas or maybe Althaus? From some other series....

Comment: @Randal'Thor I meant to add that in...

Answer (score 3):

Searching on [google books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=IQIM2G5V0CcC&pg=PA299&dq=%22Althus%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Althus%22&f=false) for the word "Althus" immediately came up with some matches;

A character named Althus features in the [Dragon Stone Trilogy](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=gd4ZYOqOlaMC&pg=PA328&dq=%22Althus%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Althus%22&f=false) by Debra McIntyre. It would appear (from the hundreds of matches) that this individual is the main character *across the entire book series.*

---

A minor character named Althus appears in the [The Red Knight](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15774644-the-red-knight) by K.T. Davies. This individual appears in several chapters and seems to be some sort of guard captain.

Comment: I don't remember an Althus in the Septimus Heap books. Are you sure you're not thinking of [Alth**er** Mella](http://septimusheap.wikia.com/wiki/Alther_Mella), who is a ghostly sorcerer?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Looking over the reviews, it looks like they renamed the character in later editions. I'll remove them until I can find a better source.

Comment: Thanks guys this does help... I did do some googleing but didn't come up with anything as conclusive as this.